# How do I show permissions rationale for multiple permissions request?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-permissions, android-dialog

I am working with Android API 25 and need to make permissions requests in the app.

There are a ton of code samples on how to make a request as well as how to show the rationale. [This link here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions/MainActivity.java) shows a simple methodology as do these: [Android M Request Multiple permission at a single time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385161/android-m-request-multiple-permission-at-a-single-time) , [Android M request permission non activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502650/android-m-request-permission-non-activity)

The problem I am having is I am requesting multiple permissions at once (Location, Write storage access, and Contacts) and the ActivityCompatApi23.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale source code only takes in a String for a single permission and not an array for multiple permissions. (source: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat)

So in my code, I can do this:

```
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionsStringArray, 123);
```

And try to request multiple at once, but I can't then show the explanation for the ones needed if they return true from:

```
     ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                    currentPerm.getPermissionManifestName()
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can show a dialog that includes multiple rationales in it as opposed to one at a time?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to show one dialog, with multiple permissions, and an explanation for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this open source.

https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission

You can use simply. for example

```
private void CheckPermission() {

        new TedPermission(this)
                .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                .setDeniedMessage(getString(R.string.str_permission1))
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .check();
    }
```

Comment: This put me on the right track, but I ultimately wrote my own. It looks like the answer is something along the lines of it can't be done for multiple, just send them to settings instead.